# Getting last dated rows from multiple IDs

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm currently making the backend of an application updater and i use my server to keep track of all files and revisions.

Currently i have two tables in my database:

```
dev_version_control_files
Columns: FileID, FileName

dev_version_control_versions
Columns: VersionID, FileID, Version, DateReleased, FileLocation
```

The files table keeps one record for every file that's under version control. The version table keeps one record for every version of each file along with the date its released, its version number and location.

Now what i want is to get the last record (update) of every file in the files table. This should be decided by the date field, that holds a unix timestamp from when it was released.

I don't want to go through every row in the version table every time an update request is made, so would it be possible to do this in one query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get first the maximum `DateReleased` for each `FileID` the join them later with `dev_version_control_files` and `dev_version_control_versions`

```
SELECT a.*, b.Version, DateReleased
FROM    dev_version_control_files a 
            INNER JOIN dev_version_control_versions b
                on a.FileID = b.FileID
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT FileID, MAX(DateReleased) MaxDate
                FROM dev_version_control_versions
                GROUP BY FileID
            ) c ON b.FileID = c.FileID AND
                   b.DateReleased = c.MaxDate
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a SQL expert, but would this work?

```
SELECT f.*, v.DateReleased
FROM dev_version_control_files f
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT FileId, MAX(DateReleased) AS DateReleased
  FROM dev_version_control_versions
  GROUP BY 1) v ON f.FileID = v.FileID
```

I'll test this out on a sample table now to see (I think some syntax may be off), but the idea is to pull the max dates from the `versions` table and group them by ID, then join to the `files`  table on ID. Is this what you were already doing?

Comment: This one didn't give me the entire rows, and it returned every 4 rows, even though there was only two, so I'm afraid its not what I'm looking for. Thanks for trying though

Comment: Gotcha - so all possible columns? I think I know why it duplicated so I'll update (learning quickly that I should test SQL before writing :) )

Comment: Yes, all fields from both table rows. But the row from the `versions` table should be the latest dated one

Comment: See if that version works. Basically I forgot to include the table to JOIN on, which doesn't help matters :) I have a crude version of it working on a local DB, so more than happy to help work until we can nail it!

Comment: John Totet Woo replied with a working version, thanks for your effort anyways!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have at least one version record in the second table:

```
SELECT FileID, FileName, MAX(DateReleased)
FROM dev_version_control_files
INNER JOIN dev_version_control_versions ON FileID
GROUP BY FileID, FileName
```

This is not exact SQL, it's a rough idea of how I would go about this.

Comment: I modified it to return the fields i needed and it works perfect, except that it doesn't return the rows with the highest date, it returns the lowest ones unfortunately. `SELECT f.FileID, f.FileName, v.Version, v.FileLocation, MAX(v.DateReleased) AS DateReleased
FROM dev_version_control_files f
INNER JOIN dev_version_control_versions v ON f.FileID
GROUP BY f.FileID, f.FileName`

Comment: Another update, it doesn't return the right dates for the right IDs either, it returns the highest of them all (Some files will not be updated every time, so it would be vital to get the latest update for the corresponding ID)